# Can you adjust the spell angle in Skyrim PSVR?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim-vr

After my PS4 installed the update for Skyrim PSVR last night, the angle for aiming spells changed significantly. Some quick googling suggests that this was intentional with Update 1.4.4. However, I preferred the previous aiming system. Is there a way to adjust or re-calibrate the spell targeting angle?

Answer (score 1):

After extensive playing and asking others, I never found a way to re-calibrate or adjust the spell angle. While proving a negative is difficult, I think it is safe to assume there is no way to adjust it.

Personally, I got used to the new angle after playing for a while longer.